# "Tunneling socket could not be established" error when doing a proxy request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

i am trying do request through proxy, but i am getting error

```
 var request = require('request')
    var proxyRequest = request.defaults({
        proxy:'http://113.161.78.86:4145',
        strictSSL :false
    });

    proxyRequest.get("https://google.com", function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(err)
      console.log(body)
    })
```

and my error code

> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up

Comment: How's your proxy set up?

Comment: can you check your proxy set up at http://113.161.78.86:4145